# Copy commits in repository A to repository B, deleting all files in B but retaining history?

Tags: git

I have two repositories:

- Repository A contains a complete, finished application.
- Repository B contains a proof-of-concept prototype application which was developed prior to the complete application.

I want to delete the prototype out of repo B (but retain the history) and apply all commits from A over to B. How can I approach this?

Comment: What's wrong with just `git rm -r .` B, committing the rm, then `git merge A/branch`? Does that not do what you want?

Comment: Thanks, that appears to have worked! Does it matter that my repo has two root nodes now?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to see both roots at the same time, right? History will just be interspersed, but since each commit tracks its parent, you'll be able to see the full history without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just merge branches that you want to merge into repo A after removing all of the data the master branch of repo B and committing the removal.

In repo B:

```
git rm -r .
git commit -m "Cleaning out prototype."
git remote add repoA /path/to/repo/A
git merge repoA/master
```

Comment: line three should be "git remote add...". I also had to do a "git fetch repoA" after line three otherwise I was getting "merge: repoA - not something we can merge".

Comment: My apologies. I've fixed this.